# Can anybody help me in solving this integration?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

i've tried all the existing methods to solve it but failed. if anybody can suggest any way to solve this that would be a great help to me.
$$\int\frac{r(r^p-1)^q}{\left(1-\frac{r-1}{r_{\rm{max}}-1}\right)^q}dr$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. What integration? Also, tell us your thoughts on it. Also, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some hints on how to write mathematical expressions on this site.

Comment: Please revise my edit.

Comment: i badly need ur help guys. i'm stuck in this for about 15 days!

Comment: Maybe you should show your solution so we can tell you where you went wrong.

Also, what is $r_1$?

Comment: i tried different approaches but unable to come up with a solution. r1 actually r_max. i simplified it.

Comment: r_1 is the maximum value of r which is not a constant

Comment: Do you say that the integral should be definite (with limits)?, and that the upper limit of $r$ is $r_1$? What is then the lower limit?

Comment: r1 is not the upper limit but a variable.

Comment: Is $q$ an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $p$ and $q$ are not dependent on $r$, we have
$$\int\frac{r(r^p-1)^q}{\left(1-\frac{r-1}{r_{\rm{max}}-1}\right)^q}dr$$
$$=\int r\left(\frac{r^p-1}{1-\frac{r-1}{r_{\rm{max}}-1}}\right)^q dr$$
$$=\int r\left(\frac{(r^p-1)(r_{\rm{max}}-1)}{r_{\rm{max}}-r}\right)^q dr$$
$$=(r_{\rm{max}}-1)^q\int r\left(\frac{r^p-1}{r_{\rm{max}}-r}\right)^q dr$$
Note that this integral does not have a solution in terms of elementary mathematical functions.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

Note that your integral can be written as:
$$(r_{max}-1)^q\int r\left(\frac{r^p - 1}{r_{max} - r}\right)^qdr$$
Which, if $q$ is a known integer, this can be expressed as sum of hypergeometric functions multiplied by powers of $r$, by expanding the numerator.

I doubt however that you can derive a generalized formula.

Comment: @k170 I did not downvote your answer, but yes it offers no new information.